# Play framework: How to require login for some actions, but not all

Tags: authentication, controller, playframework

Adding `@With(Secure.class)` to a controller blocks all unauthenticated access.  Is there a way to enabled it only for certain actions, or to except certain actions after it's enabled on a controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with the secure module. As Niels said the secure module is more an example than a solution. You can build your own security system with the @Before annotation. Here is an example:

```
public class Admin extends Controller {

@Before(unless={"login", "authenticate", "logout", "otherMethod"})
void checkAccess() {
    // check the cookie
}

public void login() {
    render();
}

public void authenticate(String email, String password) {
    // check the params and set a value in the cookie
}

public void logout() {
    // delete cookie
}
```

I recommend you to read the source code of the secure module.

Comment: You can do this even with the Secure module. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I've since found my earlier `@Public` solution somewhat limiting since it can't address inherited actions.  I've instead gone to a class-level annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AllowGuest {

    String[] value();
}
```

and added this code to the beginning of the `Secure.checkAccess()` method:

```
AllowGuest guest = getControllerInheritedAnnotation(AllowGuest.class);
if (guest != null) {
    for (String action : guest.value()) {
        if (action.equals(request.actionMethod))
            return;
    }
}
```

which can be used like this: `@AllowGuest({"list","view"})`

This makes it easy to allow access to local and inherited actions, and to see which actions in a controller are unsecured.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `@With(Secure.class)` annotation to the controller and add this piece of code inside the controller.

```
@Before(unless={"show"})
static void checkAccess() throws Throwable {
    Secure.checkAccess();
}
```

where `show` is the action you need to make publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get what I was looking for, I copied the `Check` annotation and created a `Public` annotation.

```
package controllers;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Public {

}
```

then I added these two lines to the beginning of the `Secure.checkAccess`:

```
if (getActionAnnotation(Public.class) != null)
    return;
```

Now actions in controllers using `With(Secure.class)` can be made accessible without logging in by adding a `@Public` annotation to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set at the @Before-Tag of the Secure Controller the value unless or only. The Secure-Module is more an example than a solution.

Comment: The Secure module seems to be extensible enough to do everything else I want.  Are there other shortcomings that I just haven't discovered yet?