# Play Framework User Authentication/Membership

Tags: authentication, playframework

I want to support user authentication in a Play Application. It is Web App and I think that the built-in "Secure" module is too simple for my needs. In fact, the user group discusses how the Secure module is really for demonstration purproses. However, how can I develop such a system?

Essentially, the application will allow the user to login and then they will have their own settings and so forth applied throughout the application. There are some pages for which unauthenticated users can view but if the client is authenticated, then the view of those pages will be different. Pretty simple setup but most documentation just refers to the simple Secure module.

Comment: i don't see why the default secure module don't feet your needs

Comment: @Ricardo - that's definitely not the only requirement. Secure Module has a good framework, but you still need to implement OpenID/Facebook Connect / Password salting. There are a few modules that do more: SecureSocial and OpenID for once, but SecureSocial is very new and still a bit raw, and OpenID is too basic.

Answer (score 4):

If your only special requirement is that some pages be publicly visible, I've got your answer: [Play framework: How to require login for some actions, but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328455/play-framework-how-to-require-login-for-some-actions-but-not-all/4473052#4473052) .  I just copied the Secure module and made a few small additions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PlayPlugins for this. I started to write a plugin which enabled Security in powerful way. It's an migration from [BasisSecurity for](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gsec) Grails. At the moment I don't find the time to further development. You can see the current state here https://code.launchpad.net/~opensource21/+junk/permsec.

Answer (score 2):

from your requirements the current authentication module seems enough. If not, what I did for my project was:

- Copy the classes from the module (Secure controller, the annotation, the tag) to your project
- Extend the controller adding additional functionalities

I don't have my code handy to put samples here, but in general I:

- renamed the classes (so apologies if I say one name meaning another, don't remember the original names!)
- added methods in Secure Controller to handle OpenId and OAUth authentication
- added support methods in my User model that given the Id of a service (Google OpenId, Twitter id, etc) returns an existing user from the DB with that ID, or if it doesn't exists creates and returns a new user linked to that id.
- added some flags (like admin, supervisor, etc) to User class
- modified the check method in security controller so it checks the values of the annotation with the flags of the user. Something like (pseudocode)

  var ok : Boolean = false
  ok = ok || (annotation.value == "admin" && currentUser.isadmin)
  ok = ok || (annotation.value == "supervisor" && currentUser.issupervisor)
  ...
- added the annotation to the corresponding methods, and added the Secure controller (via @With) tot he classes that require access check

With this I have a secured system, and it seems to work quite well (fingers crossed :P)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it could help you but look at the deadbolt module to manage access rights to views/controllers...
http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt-1.0/home